# What are the steps for creating ipa file?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I want to give a ipa file to a tester.
I first create a new Provisioning profile that is ad hoc . After I download it and I see in organizer xcode could not find a valid private key certificate pair for this profile in your keychain.
I tried to arhive application and create ipa but it does not work for the other programmmer. Where should i add the test.mobileprovision?
When I create this one I choose the developer for which i have certificate in my keychain 
Thanks ,
Raluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> xcode could not find a valid private key certificate pair for this
>   profile in your keychain

seems to indicate that you have no Distribution certificate in your keychain.

To build ad-hoc applications, you will need a distribution certificate, as well as a distribution provisioning profile.

The guide in your Provisioning Portal explains step by step how to build an app for ad-hoc distribution:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Also [here](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/) is good guide to help you build your app for ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

- add devices UDID, you want use for testing, to Apple Developer portal
- modify Profile by adding devices, application identifiers and developers at Apple Developer  Portal
- download and install profile in your system by drop profile to Library section in organizer
- install profile to all tester's devices
- download developer keys and install it via Keychain Access application
- sign your build with this keys
- then archive your build and share it to ipa via organizer

Also you can use 3rd services, such as [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/builds/) or [Beta builder](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder) to share your application between testers.

Testflight mush easier then manual sending builds to testers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer steps for AdHoc Distribution

I think you need to login with your credentials at Developer Apple Login

Once you are logged in go through this link and read through it step by step.

I think this is the best solution you can get as this documentation guide is given by Apple

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

This has multiple steps like:

```
1. Generating a Certificate Signing Request

2. Submitting a Certificate Signing Request for Approval

3. Approving Certificate Signing Requests

4. Downloading and Installing Development Certificates

5. Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems
```

I think if you read all this steps on the apple documentation at the given link then you don't need to refer to any other guide.

STEP-2:

Then just you need to download your certificates and provisioning profile.

STEP-3:

Just set the profile into your Project and Target Settings and then put proper Entitlements using "Entitlements.plist".

STEP-4:

Once you have done that, just set up your project in AdHoc Scheme.

STEP-5:

Clean your Project.

STEP-6:

Go to Product -> Click on Build For -> "Build For Archiving"

STEP-7:

Product -> Archive

Now your Archive can be obtained in your Organizer where in you can save it to disk with an IPA extension and send it your client.