# How to distribute ios app with development provisional

Tags: ios, testing, provisioning-profile

My team is migrating in to a new Testing flow.

With two parts.

1. testing the app on test servers.
2. testing the app on production servers.

For testing the on production we are using TestFlight/Fabric Beta

My problem is with distributing the app with test servers and development provisionals (for dev push certificates)

Is there a way to distribute the test app without having the phone on location? (are testers are in a different country)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this virtual testing online, you need to upload your **ipa** file

https://portal.kobiton.com/devices?survey=true

1.Device token will not generate.

2.I am not aware of location upadation

Comment: found one more online virtual testing device https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone5s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=9.3

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you can distribute your app for testing without having the phone in your office.

Provided your `ipa` file has  **[UDID](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/UDID) of device (iPhone/iPad) which is added in [apple member center](https://developer.apple.com/account/) and chosen in the [Development Provisional certificate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)**

EDIT : 
[StackOverflow thread to generate a ipa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433480/what-are-the-steps-for-creating-ipa-file) file from Xcode.

Comment: I didn't understand what i need to do.
How do i get the IPA file and what do you mean by choosing the dev provisional certificate? where do i choose?

Comment: Well, I will add link in my answer for generating ipa file.