# Distribute iOS Application without an Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

As far as I know, an iOS Application can be distributed in the following ways

1. Via App Store
2. Using TestFlight
3. Using HockeyApp or something similar
4. Sharing the .ipa file

But all the above require enrolling in the Apple Developer Program. I can test the app on my device using my apple id but I alse need to share my app with a couple of personal friends(testers). Is there any way to share an iOS application without enrolling in the Apple Developer Program?

Thanks.

Comment: No but you can test it in online via virtual devices

Comment: Could you point me to any such platform available online?

Comment: check here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181568/how-to-distribute-ios-app-with-development-provisional/43181742#43181742

Comment: Generating an ipa file requires you to be enrolled in the Developer Program.

Comment: No need there is lot of way to take ipa file

Comment: Could you share with me couple of those ways that work?

Comment: I assume your friends can't drop by for you to build your app to their device once per week?  If not, it is going to be difficult unless you get all your friends to jailbreak their devices to allow them to run unsigned code. Basically apple's code signing is meant to prevent what you are trying to do.  Otherwise people could create a 3rd party App Store.

Answer (score 7):

Have the tester remote into your machine and share the USB. Apple is none the wiser. I have windows 7 running High Sierra via virtual box. I share the USB from Windows to Mac. I have my testers use a program like Team Viewer, which allows them to share their iPhone USB with me(not sure if it works with the mac version, so I daisy-chain USB sharing)

So it goes: Tester<---[TeamViewer]--->Windows Machine---[VirtualBox]--->Mac OSX

Answer (score 5):

Well, Legally you can't do that, apple hasn't provided this till now and i guess they never will be, you have to enrol in Apple Developer account to test upto in 100 devices in Development and as production with adHoc mode through IPA.

Thanks

Comment: At this point I am not too particular about legal methods. I am looking for a quick fix to circumvent this dependency.

Comment: No, Apple provides all the limited and legal way, and you have to go through in their way.  Their is no short cut to jump over their way, They made all things this way that all things are fixed and you have to go through on their way only.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score -4):

Check the accepted answer at, [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak).

**The Xcode 7, now allows you to deploy your apps on any of your devices, simply by logging in with your Apple ID. You will no longer need a paid Program membership to deploy apps on your own device.**

Comment: Yes, I am aware of free provisioning. But that requires you to physically connect your device to the mac. I would like to share the app over the air with testers.